# Redis-node library discard transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, redis

Actually i'm using the excelent library redis-node.
But, I don't know how to make the following case to work:

I have a quantity field passed by param, then, inside a for loop, i need to use LPOP to extract the items from a first list, and RPUSH into another list, and the quantities must be the same, all inside a transaction block.

So, if the quantity param and the items extracted are different, i wan't to DISCARD the transaction, is this possible?

I put a piece of code that i've at the moment.

```
var redisNode = require('redis-node');
var client = redisNode.createClient();
var qty = req.params.qty;

// init transaction, lpop first and rpush finally
client.transaction(function () {
   for (var i=0; i <= qty; i++) {
       client.lpop(initStockListKey, function (err, item) {                        
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log('[assign] CREATE TRANSACTION list %s, pop %s', initStockListKey, item);  
           inProgressItems.push(item);
       });
   }

   // pop qty validation, DISCARD
   if (inProgressItems.length != qty) {
       client.discard(function (err, status) {
           console.log('[assign] DISCARD TRANSACTION err %s status %s', err, status);  
       })
   }       
});
```

I have the following error running this code:

```
ERR EXEC without MULTI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `MULTI` in the right way. Check the following `node_redis` documentation sample found in the library's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis):

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(), multi;

// start a separate multi command queue
multi = client.multi();
multi.incr("incr thing", redis.print);
multi.incr("incr other thing", redis.print);

// runs immediately
client.mset("incr thing", 100, "incr other thing", 1, redis.print);

// drains multi queue and runs atomically
multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 101, 2
});

// you can re-run the same transaction if you like
multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies); // 102, 3
    client.quit();
});
```

In Redis, `EXEC` marks the end of an atomic operation started by `MULTI`.

Comment: Can you DISCARD the transaction or this is managed by redis? I mean like a rollback

Comment: @EzequielMiranda If `EXEC` isn't executed, the data isn't persisted. You should read Redis docs about MULTI commands and you'll get a better knowledge about the topic. http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Comment: Thanks for the info!, I will read it, sorry, but i'm using redis-node in this case, https://github.com/bnoguchi/redis-node